# How to fix "PegaRULES initialization failed. Server: unknown"

Tags: tomcat5.5, pega

I'm setting up a new server for pega application. While starting the JVM, i'm facing below error. please help on below.

**Version**

```
apache_tomcat = 5.5.17
java = 1.5.0_22
OS = Linux
```

Is there any configuration need to be added?

**Error**

2018-12-20 09:38:33,101 [                main] [          ] [                    ] (    etier.engine.EngineStartup) ERROR   - PegaRULES initialization failed. Server: unknown
    com.pega.pegarules.pub.database.ConnectionException: Database-General   Problem encountered when getting connection for database pegarules      0               Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    From: (unknown)
    Caused by SQL Problems.
    Problem #1, SQLState null, Error code 0: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ExceptionInformation.createExceptionDueToDBFailure(ExceptionInformation.java:146)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1108)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:783)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.rebuildDBNameDefinitions(ConnectionManager.java:1970)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.(ConnectionManager.java:462)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.getInstance(ConnectionManager.java:560)
            at com.pega.pegarules.etier.engine.EngineStartup.initEngine(EngineStartup.java:393)
            at com.pega.pegarules.etier.impl.EngineImpl._initEngine_privact(EngineImpl.java:125)
            at com.pega.pegarules.etier.impl.EngineImpl.doStartup(EngineImpl.java:98)
            at com.pega.pegarules.web.servlet.WebAppLifeCycleListener.contextInitialized(WebAppLifeCycleListener.java:203)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3729)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4187)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:809)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:698)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1122)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:310)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1021)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1013)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:442)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:709)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:551)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:766)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.DataSourceManager.getConnection(DataSourceManager.java:251)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.DatabaseConnection.activate(DatabaseConnection.java:1113)
            at com.pega.pegarules.engine.database.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1077)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:760)
            ... 36 more
    2018-12-20 09:38:33,101 [                main] [          ] [                    ] (    etier.engine.EngineStartup) INFO    - PegaRULES initialization failed. Server: unknown

Comment: What is the Pega Version ? Is it a personal edition or Enterprise edition ?

Comment: @AJ: Enterprise edition 5.3Version

Comment: did you go through the Application Requirement guide and Installation guide ?

Comment: Your requirements look fine fine to me. Please go through the Installation guide. Might be some DB configuration is missing.

Comment: @AJ. Okay. Same is working fine in my windows. one more thing i'm not sure why it's throwing server as unknown. 2018-12-20 09:38:33,101 [ main] [ ] [ ] ( etier.engine.EngineStartup) ERROR - PegaRULES initialization failed. Server:

Comment: did you copy the Database JDBC driver file to tomcat ?

Comment: @AJ: yes. I copied everything

Answer (score 0):

There could be three reasons or others..

1) JDK version is not correct --> I will recommend to use JDK 1.8

2) Database service is not running --> I am not sure how you check active services in Linux

3) Database JDBC jar file is not copied to tomcat's lib folder

4) JVM memory allotted is not enough --> Allot at-least 4 GB

Please go through the installation guide.
https://community.pega.com/system/files/pdfs/ProductSupport/Products/PegaRULESProcessCommander/documents/PRPC/V5/503/PRPC5-3_J2EE_Install_Guide_Tomcat.pdf